# Call UIButton @IBAction from NSTimer function

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, nstimer

I have a UIButton added programmatically  with action

```
@objc func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton!) {
}
```

I want to call the above function from below timer selector

```
@objc func preResult(timer: Timer) {
}
```

How can i do it?

Comment: Question not clear, can you explain clearly ?

Comment: I want to launch my UI button from the timer function

Answer (score 1):

With a code snippet below the buttonAction will be called by a timer closure and when a user will tap a button.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var button: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 40))

    var timer: Timer?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Create a timer which will call a closure with an argument timer
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 4, repeats: true, block: { (timer) in
            self.perform(#selector(self.buttonAction))
        })

        // Add a button to a view
        view.addSubview(button)

        // Assign a function to call when a button is tapped
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc func buttonAction() {
        print("button tapped")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to do sth in your timer event, and update your button UI with the result you got?

If so, just set button' title/ color (whatever you want to update) at the end of your event. And remember to do that in the main thread.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    // update UI
}
```